# How do I tell vasm to allow white spaces?

Tags: amiga, assembly, motorola-68000

I have recently been learning to use `vasm`.  For those that don't know, vasm is a cross-platform assembler for multiple types of processors such as the M68000.

http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/

I am using it to write some Amiga specific (A1200) code in assembler.

For about 15 minutes, I could not figure out why I couldn't assemble a simple program until I discovered it was the white space between operands.

For example, the following does not work:

```
moveq #0, D0
```

But this does work:

```
moveq #0,D0
```

I have a habit of putting spaces after commas when I code and vasm does not like that.  I have searched online and cannot find a reference to that issue.

The following is how I assemble the program if it helps:

```
vasm -m68020 -kick1hunks -Fhunkexe -o test.exe main.asm
```

Any idea how to tell vasm to not be so picky?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use `-phxass` option (name of the old Amiga native assembler by Phx/Frank Wille who is also the author of the Motorola syntax module)

```
vasm -phxass -m68020 -kick1hunks -Fhunkexe -o test.exe main.asm
```

From the [documentation](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm.html):

> ‘-phxass’
>
> PhxAss-compatibility mode. Only directives known to PhxAss are recognized. Enables the following features:
>
> - Enable escape codes handling in strings (see ‘-esc’).
> - Macro names are treated as case-insensitive.
> - Up to 35 macro arguments.
> - **Allow blanks in operands**
> - Defines the symbol *PHXASS* with value 2 (to differentiate from the real PhxAss with value 1).
> - When no output file name is given, construct it from the input name.
> - Directives unknown to PhxAss are no longer supported.

It comes with some other syntax changes (ex: `blk.b` is allowed too) but it's pretty similar to devpac syntax, only more comprehensive. I'm using it for one of my projects when I migrated from phxass assembler, and using devpac option for other sources where I used Barfly before and I want others to be able to still use Barfly on those sources.

Answer (score 8):

Adding command line option `-spaces` will do the trick by allowing spaces within operands. This means of course that comments now must be separated by `;` from any instruction or directrive. Unlike with `-phxass` (which includes `-spaces`), there are no other side effects.

The option is only available with Motorola syntax (`vasmm68k_mot`).

---

On a sidenote, it may be useful to drop that habit when doing assembler, as not many will be so kind to allow it.

Comment: yeah, comments using `*` now trigger an error since they're seen as a multiplication.